# Page not found after redirect from other site with parameters

Tags: http-status-code-404, url-parameters

I am trying to get a redirect working from site a to site b with a parameter in the url. For example, I want to go from example.com to mysite.com?code=abc

When doing so, I get a 404 error. The page could not be found. When I manually browse to mysite.com?code=abc , it does get found. Does anyone know what causes this issue? All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's just Intellij which doesn't support this. I tried with another site and it turned out fine.